# Считывание и разбиение файла

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть файл - name.txt, в этом файле на каждой строке есть пара имён: Владимир - Оксана и т.п, не могу понять как открыть этот файл, найти в нём символ "-" убрать символ и перенести, то, что осталось после него на следующую строку. Пример:

```
Владимир - Оксана
Антон - Егор
Алексей - Александр
```

После обработки:

```
Владимир
    Оксана
    Антон
    Егор
    Алексей
    Александр
```

Answer (score 1):

И так. Начнем по порядку.

> не могу понять как открыть этот файл

Есть несколько способов для открытия файла. В Вашем случае подойдет функция [file()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php).
На выходе этой функции Вы получите массив. Каждый элемент массива будет содержать одну строку из файла.

> найти в нём символ "-"

По сути Вам нужно получить массив из двух значений. Например было "Владимир - Оксана
". В один элемент массива должно попасть одно имя а в другой элемент массива другое имя.
Для этого можно передавать по очереди(в цикле) в функцию [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). На выходе у вас будет массив из двух элементов.

Затем Вам нужно с помощью операции "конкатенации" соединить должным образом элементы массива. Скажу еще, что перевод строки это символ "\n".

Рабочий код, Вам, я думаю никто не даст потому, что Вы сами ничего не сделали и не потрудились почитать документацию. Так что посмотрите те ссылки, которые я Вам дал. Если у Вас есть голова на плечах то они Вам должны помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('file.txt');
// если вывести на экран
echo str_replace(' - ', '<br>', $txt);
// если записать/переписать файл
$new_str = str_replace(' - ', "\r\n", $txt); // (!!!) /r/n - в двойные кавычки
file_put_contents('file2.txt',$new_str);
```